Ubuntu 22.04 froze when modifying files on Samsung 870 SSD
I recently swapped my old drives for 2 new SSDs:

One is a Samsung 980 SSD (NVMe), where I install Ubuntu 22.04. Also dual-booting with Windows 10 installed on this same SSD, on another partition.
The other one is a Samsung 870 SSD (SATA), where I store my working data

However today my computer froze twice when I did these things:

Search across files in VSCode (in a project saved on the Samsung 870). The computer immediately froze when I started to type in the search keyword and VSCode started indexing files in the project
Building docker images locally for my projects, also saved on the 870 (I don't remember the exact build step where my computer froze)

Note that these instances happened consecutively: after rebooting to get out of the first instance, I immediately encountered the second one.
Some other information / What I have done to isolate the issue:

I also notice my laptop fan running much louder everytime I did something with the Samsung 870, e.g. deleting files,  moving files, etc. However the SSD temp is only around 45-50°C
Everytime the computer froze, I had to hard shut down using the power button, and when booting back up, I had to do a file system repair for the Samsung 870 using Disks.
I have temporarily moved my projects to the Ubuntu partition on the Samsung 980 and so far have not experienced similar freezing issues. I also have never experienced the same problem with my old SSD where I stored my files in the same partition I installed Ubuntu on.
I have used smartctl to check both SSDs and they are both in good condition. Particularly for the 870, see result below.
I have used Windows 10 for video games installed on the Samsung 870 and have not experienced any lag or freezing at all, so I suspect that the issue is isolated within Ubuntu only.

Question: Since this issue only happen on the Samsung 870 SATA and in Ubuntu only, I feel like this is not a hardware issue and that there might be some configuration that can be done to solve this?
My laptop spec:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: Strix 15 GL503GE 1.0 
Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic 
Uptime: 46 mins 
Packages: 1956 (dpkg), 15 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-prussiangreen-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-prussiangreen [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: tilix 
CPU: Intel i7-8750H (12) @ 4.100GHz 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile 
Memory: 3962MiB / 31940MiB 

smartctl result for Samsung 870:
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB
Serial Number:    S7BWNJ0WB47795Y
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 f33b32a62
Firmware Version: SVT02B6Q
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Apr 21 02:33:10 2024 +07
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       86
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       55
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   063   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       647008219
252 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


Are your firmware versions, the latest available from Samsung & system? I do not have Windows, so have downloaded the ISO for my version of SSD & NVMe both are Samsung. The ISO look like old DOS screens and only update one drive. I do not know smart status, but just think passed usually, but not always, means drive is ok. Hard reboot if system is running (indexing something) often then needs e2fsck repairs.
